# JedisSentinelPool class can not connect redis which deployed using Docker in virtual machines

Tags: docker, redis, jedis

In the virtual machine, I use Docker to deploy Redis and Redis Sentinels.
Here is the container information：

| container name | Ip Address | Port |
| --- | --- | --- |
| redis-sentinel2 | 172.17.0.8 | 26380:26380 |
| redis-sentinel1 | 172.17.0.7 | 26379:26379 |
| redis3 | 172.17.0.6 | 6381:6381 |
| redis2 | 172.17.0.5 | 6380:6380 |
| redis | 172.17.0.4 | 6379:6379 |

redis is master.redis2 and redis3 are slave.redis-sentinel1 and redis-sentinel2 are sentinels.
Then I exposed the port to the host.Each port corresponds one by one.My virtual machine uses net mode and host only mode for networking.net mode ip address is 192.168.39.107.host only mode ip address is 192.168.56.107.
Then when I run the following code:

```
public class JedisSentinel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
        hashSet.add("127.0.0.1:26379");
        hashSet.add("127.0.0.1:26380");
        JedisSentinelPool jedisSentinelPool = new JedisSentinelPool("SH1",hashSet);
        Jedis jedis = jedisSentinelPool.getResource();
        jedis.auth("000000");
        jedis.set("key", "value");
        String result = jedis.get("key");
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        jedis.close();
        jedisSentinelPool.close();
    }
}
```

It reported the following error:

```
10:58:44.335 [main] DEBUG redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool - Connecting to Sentinel 192.168.56.101:26379
10:58:46.354 [main] WARN redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool - Cannot get master address from sentinel running @ 192.168.56.101:26379. Reason: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. Trying next one.
```

After debugging, I discovered the following code：

```
if (inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() || host.equals("0.0.0.0") || host.startsWith("169.254"))
        return getLocalhost();
...
public boolean isLoopbackAddress() {
        /* 127.x.x.x */
        byte[] byteAddr = getAddress();
        return byteAddr[0] == 127;
    }
```

Is this normal for port forwarding?Should I report the error to Jedis?
Then I modified the code：

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
        //my host only ip address
        hashSet.add("192.168.56.107:26379");
        hashSet.add("192.168.56.107:26380");
        JedisSentinelPool jedisSentinelPool = new JedisSentinelPool("SH1",hashSet);
        Jedis jedis = jedisSentinelPool.getResource();
        jedis.auth("000000");
        jedis.set("key", "value");
        String result = jedis.get("key");
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        jedis.close();
        jedisSentinelPool.close();
    }
```

Then it reported the following error:

```
11:06:49.233 [main] INFO redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool - Trying to find master from available Sentinels...
11:06:49.235 [main] DEBUG redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool - Connecting to Sentinel 192.168.56.107:26379
11:06:49.262 [main] DEBUG redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool - Found Redis master at 172.17.0.4:6379
11:06:49.262 [main] INFO redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool - Redis master running at 172.17.0.4:6379, starting Sentinel listeners...
11:06:49.371 [main] INFO redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool - Created JedisPool to master at 172.17.0.4:6379
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host 172.17.0.4:6379
```

Here is the configuration file for my Redis Sentry：

```
port 26379
protected-mode no
daemonize no
sentinel monitor SH1 172.17.0.4 6379 2
sentinel auth-pass SH1 000000
```

It seems that Jedis only obtains the configuration file of redis sentinel and connects to Redis through the information provided in the configuration file.
When I connect Redis-cli in the redis Sentinel container and execute the "info Sentinel" command, the following results are obtained:

```
# Sentinel
sentinel_masters:1
sentinel_tilt:0
sentinel_tilt_since_seconds:-1
sentinel_running_scripts:0
sentinel_scripts_queue_length:0
sentinel_simulate_failure_flags:0
master0:name=SH1,status=ok,address=172.17.0.4:6379,slaves=2,sentinels=2
```

When my Redis Sentry's configuration file is modified：

```
sentinel monitor SH1 127.0.0.1 6379 2
```

The Redis Sentinel and Redis database do not seem to be connected：

```
master0:name=SH1,status=down,address=127.0.0.1:6379,slaves=0,sentinels=1
```

It seems that there is no way to connect to my Redis database through JedisSentinelPool.
Does anyone have any solution？

Connect to my Redis database through JedisSentinelPool